# Proper Class Modeling With UML

Tags: oop, class, uml

I'm getting started with UML after years of programming and I want to make sure that I'm properly using the symbols in my diagrams.

Does the following diagram look like a proper representation of a simple Car class?

[image: original model]

Update:

Actually, I just realized that Make knows about model so I removed the arrowhead, but Make and Model do not know about Car so I added arrowheads:

[image: revised model]

Comment: Why does the Engine have a composition relationship with the car?What does your domain sasy about the relationship between the car and its engine?Are you sure that, if your car is dismantled or crashes, you cannot reuse the engine in another car?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would make some adjustments to your original diagram:

### Make

- The Make identifies the manufacturer, so Make will have many Models, and because no other manufacturer can take ownership of those models, the black diamond is shown to denote composition
- The relationship is bidirectionally navigable, so no arrows are shown
- Because we can navigate from Make to Model, there is a SortedSet (sorted by year) of Models shown in Make

### Model

- Model holds the only direct relationship to Make; this guarantees the validity of the relationships and avoids incorrect connections that could result from allowing other classes to create relationships with Make
- Because Model may be used to navigate to Make, Model contains a reference to its Make; this ensures that any Car may navigate to its Model information and from there (and only there) navigate to its Make
- For year, the immutable type Integer was chosen, because the value will never change once it has been assigned

### Car

- The relationship between Model and Car is only navigable from Car to Model, because the business domain has no need to obtain a set of all Cars that mere manufactured for any given Model (and it keeps things simpler)
- Each car is assigned a VIN, shown as an instance of UUID - Universally Unique Identifier
- The relationship between Car and Engine is only navigable from Car to Engine, so Car has an Engine member; there are use cases where parts of the system that receive a reference to a Car may want to navigate to the Car's Engine

### Engine

- Given that an Engine may start its life in one Car but then be moved into a different Car, the relationship is shown using a white diamond, denoting aggregation
- The Engine is assigned a Part Number, which is a specific identifier for that instance of Engine; therefore the immutable type String is shown
- The Engine maintains a mileage counter, which is defined to be of type: int, because the value is mutable and will change over the lifetime of the Engine

[image]

I hope this is helpful and provides some good feedback that makes your modeling exercise thought provoking. I know I had fun creating the diagram and thinking about the relationships and some of the details. Haven't done this in awhile -

Comment: Fantastic explanation. Thank you so much, all makes perfect sense.